# How to fix syntax in UNPIVOT command? Parenthesis as Unexpected syntax error

Tags: sql

I am trying to unpivot this table as I need the days in rows not in columns. I am relatively new, but I thing the Unpivot should work. However, it says Syntax Error, unexpected (, when from everywhere I have seen there is a parenthesis after the UNPIVOT command.

I have tried other clauses to encapsulate it, or not using at all, but always appears the same mistake. It should be in Standard SQL.

## standardSQL

```
SELECT service_id, day, service
FROM calendar
UNPIVOT
(
    service
    FOR day in ( monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday, saturday, sunday )
) AS unpvt;
```

Should get a list whose column titles should be: service_id, day, service

Comment: Which dbms are you using? The ANSI/ISO SQL standard has no UNPIVOT.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way-

```
SELECT service_id, service, day
FROM calendar
UNPIVOT
(
    S FOR day in ( [monday], [tuesday], [wednesday], [thursday], [friday], [saturday], [sunday] )
) AS unpvt;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `unpivot` in standard SQL.  My preferred method is lateral joins, but that differs by database.

A generic method is to just use `union all`:

```
select service_id, 'monday' as day, monday as service
from calendar
union all
select service_id, 'tuesday' as day, tuesday as service
from calendar
union all
select service_id, 'wednesday' as day, wednesday as service
from calendar
union all
select service_id, 'thursday' as day, thursday as service
from calendar
union all
select service_id, 'friday' as day, friday as service
from calendar
union all
select service_id, 'saturday' as day, saturday as service
from calendar
union all
select service_id, 'sunday' as day, sunday as service
from calendar;
```